# JSON Date being displayed with different time zone than saved on server

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am having a problem displaying dates in application views when I host the site on the SmarterASP.net server. Basically, when retrieving dates and displaying in views, the time zone changes automatically without me having set it up - I don't know if it's automatic from ASP.NET MVC, but I haven't set anything at all. For example, these are some dates entered in the database:

[image]

To retrieve a particular record, I use JsonResult which returns the information needed for that record:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Get(Guid? id)
{
    var model = db.Student.Find(id);

    return Json(new
    {
        model.Id,
        model.Name,
        model.CreatedDate
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In the view, an AJAX request is called to display the information:

```
function getStudentInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        url: `@Url.Action("Get")`,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { id },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result.CreatedDate);
        }
    });
}
```

Thus, the date presented in the console for the first record of the first figure is: `/Date(1570551060227)/`

Also, I use a JavaScript function to convert the JSON date to a valid format:

```
function formatDataHoraJson(date, seconds) {
    if (!date)
        return "";
    const formattedDate = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
    const day = formattedDate.getDate();
    var month = formattedDate.getMonth();
    month += 1; 
    const year = formattedDate.getFullYear();

    const hour = formattedDate.getHours();
    const minute = formattedDate.getMinutes();
    const second = formattedDate.getSeconds();

    if (seconds)
        return pad(day, 2) + "/" + pad(month, 2) + "/" + pad(year, 4) + " - " + (pad(hour, 2) + ":" + pad(minute, 2) + ":" + pad(second, 2));
    else
        return pad(day, 2) + "/" + pad(month, 2) + "/" + pad(year, 4) + " - " + (pad(hour, 2) + ":" + pad(minute, 2));
}
```

The result, after calling the function, is always displayed 4 hours more than the date in the database (`2019-10-08 13:11:00:227`)

IMPORTANT: The server where the application is hosted is not in Brazil. However, the time zone of the date displayed on the screen is in accordance with the Brazilian time zone, although in the database the saved date is in the time zone from which the application is hosted. At first, I would like to display the date as it is stored on the database server.

Comment: is your database hosted server and from you are accessing web app has same timezone?

Comment: @Vishalmodi The hosting and database server are in a different time zone from which I am accessing. I am accessing from Brazil (UTC-3) and the server is in some country whose time zone is 4 hours less than Brazil

Comment: when you data is created, have you checked in which timezone CreatedDate is Stored?
Please check when data is Created, is it same time as your system time or different.
If you provide some more details, I can help you in better way